# The probability of needing to pick fewer than 5 people to find 3 from a certain group

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

There's a contest, with 24% portuguese people participating where 50% of portugueses read a book in the last 12 months, 39% went to the cinema, and 9% into a ballet in the same period of time. We also have spanish participating with 59%, 56%, 12% respectivelly (book, cinema ,ballet).

So now the question is : What's the probability of needing less than 5 people to find 3 spanish that went to a ballet.

What I tried was the following: So what I did (with no success) was first multiply 0.76*0.12 to find the probability of going to a ballet and being spanish. Then I tried using the Binomial Distribution with 5 cases ( the 5 contestants) with x as 3 (the number of spanish people) and using the 0.75*0.12=0.09 as the probability of success, but after the calculations were all done I was still left with no correct answer. 
I

I also tried going with a differetn approach ( a lit bit more extense) by doing everything "manual" by making the sum of having 3 spanish people that went into a ballet in 5 contestants, then in 4 contestants and finally 3 contestants, but still with no luck.

I'm in need of a bit of light to help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way using $bin~(4,0.09)$ is to find P(**at least** $3$ successes in $4$ trials), = 0.00272

Assuming that the larger example you cited is $bin(200,0.09), P(X\ge10)$, you could reduce computation using the complement, or use the normal/poisson approximation as appropriate

Comment: I did my calculations again and I got indeed the correct answer, thanks for all the help.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I think that your first approach comes close. If $S$ denotes success and $N$ no success then needing less than $5$ people to find $3$ Spanish that went to ballet comes to finding the probabilities of the disjoint events:

- $SSS$
- $NSSS$
- $SNSS$
- $SSNS$

and find the summation of these probabilities.

Comment: Yes, i guess that would work. But how would I go if instead of 4 contestants, we would have to choose for example 10 Spanish from a group of 200 contestants, there would be alot of possibilities and by that approach I guess it wouldn't be pratical.

Comment: A lot? I disagree on that. $P(SSS)$ is one, and of course $P(NSSS)=P(SNSS)=P(SSNS)$. So you are bound to find $2$ probabilities. The fact that you used percentages in your question is an indication that we are dealing with large numbers. This justifies the use of binomial distribution. Doing so you will find $P(SSS)=P(S)^3$ and $P(NSSS)=(1-P(S))P(S)^3$. That's all. With smaller numbers you must drop binomial and the situation becomes a bit more complex. But again it is not difficult to find these probabilities.